# Updating an immutable sequence

Tags: ceylon

I have a sequence in Ceylon and I want to make a new sequence with one of the elements replaced with something else according an index:

```
[String*] strings = ["zero", "one", "two"];
value index = 1;
value newElement= "uno";
[String*]? newStrings = ???; // should be ["zero", "uno", "two"]
```

In Scala, this is called `update`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem, and I *do* like the solution by [Quintesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889926/quintesse) above, using `Array`. That is, perhaps, what I would do in practice. However, there is one possibly-important downside of the `Array` solution: it allocates memory *twice*.

So let me just suggest a couple of different options, for the sake of completeness:

#### Using stream operations

This works, but is a bit verbose:

```
[String*] strings = ["zero", "one", "two"];
value index = 1;
value newElement= "uno";
[String*] newStrings = 
    strings.take(index)
           .chain(strings.skip(index+1).follow(newElement))
           .sequence();
```

Note that here we are using the lazy stream operations `take()`, `skip()`, `chain()` and `follow()` to create a lazy stream of elements, and then the `sequence()` operation to take a copy into a new sequence. It allocates just once, in the call to `sequence()`.

#### Using `patch()`

This also works:

```
[String*] strings = ["zero", "one", "two"];
value index = 1;
value newElement= "uno";
[String*] newStrings = 
        strings.patch([newElement], index, 1)
               .sequence();
```

Note that if it's good enough to get back an immutable `List`, you could drop the call to `sequence()`, resulting in:

```
[String*] strings = ["zero", "one", "two"];
value index = 1;
value newElement= "uno";
[String*] newStrings = 
        strings.patch([newElement], index, 1);
```

And in this case there's no allocation at all (except for one trivial instance of `List.Patch`).

See the [docs for `List.patch()`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.2.0/module-doc/api/List.type.html#patch).

Comment: patch! That's what I was looking for. I must have autocompleted every other word in English: replace, update, exchange, insert, put, ...

Comment: Patch is a great word though, since it implies placing something on top of something else so it looks different, but is not changed under the patch. Those other words would have sounded like you changed the original list.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with a comprehension:

```
[String*] newStrings = [for (i->e in strings.indexed) i==index then newElement else e];
```

[Try online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=6447046ae03c2d01a9fb)

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to copy it to an Array, which *is* mutable, and then back:

```
[String*] strings = ["zero", "one", "two"];
value index = 1;
value newElement= "uno";

value array = Array(strings);
array.set(index, newElement);

[String*] newStrings = array.sequence();
```